# RollupError: Node tried to load your configuration as an ES module even though it is likely CommonJS

Tags: reactjs, rollupjs

I am trying to build a library of components in React, and I am using Rollup to bundle things up. It is the first time that I am using it and I have watched a couple of tutorials and followed their setup (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHQi5a0TmMc)).
Here is my `rollup.config.js` file:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
    {
        input: "src/index.ts",
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main, //CommonJS
                format: "cjs",
                sourcemap: true,
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module, //ES6
                format: "esm",
                sourcemap: true, 
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
        ]
    },
    {
        input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
        output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
        plugins: [dts()],
    }
];
```

Now, when I run rollup, I am getting the error below. I have tried changing the file extension or use the flag as suggested, but the solutions are not working.
Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following steps:

1. Add the line `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file
2. Add this line `import packageJson from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };` to your `rollup.config.js` file

I hope it will be useful